# How to use QString toUtf8 and fromUtf8?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

I have a weird problem:

```
    QString s1="abc";
    const char * ss1=s1.toUtf8().constData();
    QString s2=QString::fromUtf8(ss1);
    if(s1==s2)
      qDebug()<<"s1==s2";
    else
      qDebug()<<"s1!=s2";
```

The output of the above code is "s1!=s2". In fact, the content of ss1 and s2 is a mess. But the output of the following code is "s1==s2". Why?

```
    QString s1="abc";
    QString s2=QString::fromUtf8(s1.toUtf8().constData());
    if(s1==s2)
      qDebug()<<"s1==s2";
    else
      qDebug()<<"s1!=s2";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you have undefined behavior in your code:

```
const char * ss1 = s1.toUtf8().constData();
```

The QByteArray returned by the `toUtf8()` function is a temporary object and is destroyed. But you are keeping a pointer to its data which you then try to use:

```
QString s2=QString::fromUtf8(ss1);
```

This results in undefined behavior.

For this to work, you need to keep the temporary QByteArray object alive. You can use a const reference for that. It will extend the life of the temporary object:

```
QString s1 = "abc";
const auto& bytes = s1.toUtf8();
const char * ss1 = bytes.constData();
```

Your second example is fine, because you are not using any pointers to internal memory of destroyed objects:

```
QString s2 = QString::fromUtf8(s1.toUtf8().constData());
```

The temporary QByteArray object returned by `toUtf8()` is only destroyed *after* the call to `fromUtf8()` returns. So the `constData()` pointer is valid for long enough to allow the function to read the data.

Comment: Thank you!@Nikos C.